# Как убрать пиксельность у шрифта Open Sans Google Googleapis v2?

Tags: css

Давно использую апи гугла для получения шрифтов, вчера шрифт Open Sans стал пиксельным, хотя я не трогал код, он был таким:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600&amp;subset=cyrillic,cyrillic-ext" rel="stylesheet">
```

[image: пиксельный шрифт]

Скрин шрифта 14px:

В css body стоит

```
-webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
-moz-osx-font-smoothing: auto;
```

Проблема только с font-weight: 600. Пробовал перейти googleapis v2, пробовал поставить width 550-650, не помогло, кто решил проблему?

Comment: Если верить mdn -webkit-font-smoothing и -moz-osx-font-smoothing работают только на Mac OS. Добавьте пожалуйста в вопрос какой браузер используется и на какой операционке. И минимально воспроизводимый пример также буде полезным, возможно проблема со шрифтом локальная.

Comment: @UserTest013 хром последний на винде, на мозилле тоже самое, на маке все ок.
https://lolz.guru/

Забыл добавить что есть это еще:
* {
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}